# Код срабатывает только один раз

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, web-apps

В чем суть. Начал писать рулетку, что бы руку набить, и выскочила ошибочка. После того, как кликаю на кнопку, скрипты срабатывают 1 раз, потом приходится перезагружать страницу. Выгрузил все в CodePen, если сможете решить проблему, буду очень благодарен.

[Вот сама рулетка](https://codepen.io/Zalik/pen/JjZjbeN)

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.rotateCircle');
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
let rotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
let timer;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   circle.style.transform = 'rotate(' +rotate + 'deg)';
   timer = setTimeout(winOrLose, 3500);
   function range(start = 0, end = 361, arr, step = 1){
      let count = start;
      for(let i = start; i < end; i += step){
         count++;
         arr.push(count);
      }
   }
   range(0, 135, red1);
   range(135, 315, blue);
   range(315, 360, red2);
})

const red1 = [];
const red2 = [];
const blue = [];




const redRange = [].concat(red1, red2);

function winOrLose(){
      if(blue.includes(rotate)){
         output.textContent = 'Blue';
      } else{
         output.textContent = 'Red';
      }
}
clearTimeout(timer);
```

```css
body, html{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.circle{
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   border-top: 10px solid red;
   border-left: 10px solid red;
   border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
   border-right: 10px solid blue;
   margin: 50px auto 0;
   border-radius: 50%;
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: 3s ease;
}
.rotateCircle{
   display: block;
   margin: 50px auto 0;
}
.output{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
   <div class="app">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <button class="rotateCircle">Play</button>
     <h1 class="output"></h1>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: let rotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360); надо в click занести, а то один раз вычисляется

Comment: @Виктор имеет ввиду, что объявление переменной rotate остаётся там-же (`let rotate;`), но присваивание значения (`rotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);`) выполняется в обработчике события `click`.

Comment: Да, понял, спасибо, попробую